# How to use TO_NUMBER function to update columns of a table Using oracle pl/sql

Tags: update, oracle-11g

Hope you're doing well.
I have a table with this structure :

```
Table1(Cust_No    Varchar2(50), 
       First_Name Varchar2(50), 
       Last_Name  Varchar2(50), 
       Error_Code number(1), 
       Error_Desc Varchar2(50))
```

At first , data will be inserted into column `Cust_No` and I should
Update other columns of the table based on this column.The point is that all `cust_No` must have number format. For example `Cust_No ='aa674'` does not have a correct format.
I need to write a query to `update` the table and set 
column `First_Name='--'` , column`Last_Name = '--'`,
column `Error_Code=1` and column `Error_Desc='Incorrect format'` 
for those Cust_No which has incorrect formats.
I wanted to use `TO_NUMBER()` function but it gives me invalid number error.
how may I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use UDF to detect if a value can be treated as a number. Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_for_number( check_value IN VARCHAR2 )
RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
    tmp NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF check_value IS NULL THEN
        RETURN 'Z';
    ELSE
        tmp := TO_NUMBER( check_value );
        RETURN 'Y';
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN value_error THEN
        RETURN 'N';
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN '?';
END check_for_number;
```

---

```
with test as ( select 1 id, '123' val from dual union all
               select 2   , '123asd'  from dual union all
               select 3   , 'asd'     from dual union all
               select 4   , NULL      from dual           )
select id, val, check_for_number(val)
from test;

ID  VAL     CHECK_FOR_NUMBER(VAL)
1   123     Y
2   123asd  N
3   asd     N
4   -       Z
```

Comment: Thanks but can you show me how to use regexp to handle this? I think It might be easier to use regexp rather than function

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment, requesting a regex solution:

```
update table1 set 
  error_code = 1
, error_desc = 'Incorrect format' 
where not regexp_like( cust_no, '^[0-9]+$' )
```

However, I would suggest that this is too little, too late.

You should not be allowing this defective data into the database in the first place!  (Unless this is part of a migration exercise and this is a transitional table).

Your application should be detecting this bad formatting and not even saving the record to the database.

Second Thought:

Alternatively, put the check into the table definition

[Air Code; untested]

```
create table Table1
( Cust_No Varchar2(50) 
, CHECK( regexp_like( Cust_No '^[0-9]+$' )
. . .
```

Third Thought:

If you customer number is, indeed, a *number*, then why are you storing it in the *wrong* Data Type?

```
create table Table1
( Cust_No  NUMBER 
. . .
```